# XPath query to get a descendant node of another node

Tags: xml, xpath, domdocument

I have the following HTML code

```
<html>
<body>
  ~~ optional text and variably-nested elements ~~
  <div class="a">
    ~~ optional text and variably-nested elements ~~
    <div class="b">example</div>
    ~~ optional text and variably-nested elements ~~
  </div>
  ~~ optional text and variably-nested elements ~~
  <div class="c">
    ~~ optional text and variably-nested elements ~~
    <div class="b">example</div>
    ~~ optional text and variably-nested elements ~~
  </div>
  ~~ optional text and variably-nested elements ~~
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to retrieve the `<div class="b">` DOMNode of the `<div class="c">`.

I have used:

`//*[@class='b']`

but it produced wrong results. What would be the correct XPath query to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
"//*[@class='c']//*[@class='b']"
```

http://codepad.org/EzBAWDPg

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath: `//div[@class = 'c']/div[@class = 'b']`.

It will select `div[@class = 'b']` which is child of `div[@class = 'c']`.

Comment: hum yes, i would do, but this is more complex, i edit my post since it is not really like this. But Thanks, it would have been correct for the simple case

Comment: @Keil, You mean `div[@class = 'b']` maybe descendant of `div[@class = 'c']`?